# How to solve this differential equation of first order and higher degree solvable for y

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative, indefinite-integrals

The question is $$x-yp=p^2$$.
I arrived at the value of x which is
$$x=\frac{-p^2}{2}+\frac{p}{2√(p^2-1)}log|p+√(p^2-1)|$$
But the answer is given as $$x=\frac{p}{√(p^2-1)}(c+ sin^-1p)$$
Where $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$

Answer (score 2):

We have a d'Alembert's equation $y=xf(p)+g(p)$, where $f(p)=1/p$ and $g(p)=-p$.
Differentiating with respect to $x$,
$$
p=\frac{p-xp'}{p^2}-p'
$$
and rearrange,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}p}=\frac1{p'}=\frac{x+p^2}{p(1-p^2)}
$$
i.e.,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}p}-\frac1{p(1-p^2)}x=\frac{p}{(1-p^2)}.
$$
This is a first-order linear DE.  With the integrating factor $\sqrt{1-p^2}/p$, we get
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}p}\frac{x\sqrt{1-p^2}}{p}=\frac1{\sqrt{1-p^2}}
$$
giving the answer
$$
x=\frac{p}{\sqrt{1-p^2}}(c+\sin^{-1}p).
$$

Comment: Good work, but do mention that using the last result we can get $t$ in terms of $p$. So $x=m(p)m y=n=n(p)$ contitutes the full solution of the given ODE, where $p$ acts like a free parameter:  $-1\le p \le 1$.,

Comment: @ZAhmed What is $t$?  Clearly we get $y$ from the defining $y=xf(p)+g(p)$ but this is not a problem the OP is having.

Comment: Oh! it was $y$ and not $t$ and it was $y=n(p)$. Yo are right, but a student may be given more than what he/she asked.